# Show data from 2 tables in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have a simple code, and now I want to select data from 2 tables. Then I want to show in my view. Here's my code

model:
**Tikpro.php**

```
class Tikpro extends Model {
   public $table = "TIKPRO";
   public $primaryKey = "ID_TIKPRO";

   public function permintaan() {
   return $this->hasMany('Permintaan', 'TIKPRO_ID', 'ID_TIKPRO');
}
```

model:
**Permintaan.php**

```
class Permintaan extends Model {

public $table = "PERMINTAAN";
public $fillable = array(
    'NOMOR_TICKET',
    'TGL_PERMINTAAN',
    'NAMA_REQUESTER',
    'BARANG_PERMINTAAN',
    'NO_FPBJ',
    'TGL_INPUT_FPBJ',
    'TARGET_SELESAI',
    'KETERANGAN',
    'TINDAK_LANJUT_AKHIR',
    'STATUS',
    'FPB',
    'RFQ',
    'DO',
    'BAST',
    'TGL_DEADLINE',
    'titik_proses',
    'TIKPRO_ID',
);
public $primaryKey = "ID_PERMINTAAN";

public function tikpro() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Tikpro','TIKPRO_ID','ID_TIKPRO');
}
```

Controller:
**PermintaanController.php**

```
public function details($ID_PERMINTAAN) {
    $query = DB::table('PERMINTAAN')->select('TIKPRO.NAMA_TIKPRO')->join('TIKPRO','TIKPRO.ID_TIKPRO','=','PERMINTAAN.TIKPRO_ID')->get('all');
    $jebret = Permintaan::find($ID_PERMINTAAN);
    return view('permintaan.details', compact('jebret'))->with($query);
}
```

And how can I show it? In my view I try {{ $jebret->$query }} . But still can't show the data.

How should I write code? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try this

```
public function details($ID_PERMINTAAN) {
    $query = DB::table('PERMINTAAN')->select('TIKPRO.NAMA_TIKPRO')->join('TIKPRO','TIKPRO.ID_TIKPRO','=','PERMINTAAN.TIKPRO_ID')->where('PERMINTAAN.ID_PERMINTAAN',$ID_PERMINTAAN)->get();

    return view('permintaan.details', compact('query'));
}
```

Hope this work for you

Answer (score 0):

There's 2 ways here. The first and easiest (if you've set it up correctly) is the relationship. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships. To use the one in your example you want to do this:

```
$permintaans = Permintaan::query()->get()->all();

return view('permintaan.details', [
    'permintaans' => $permintaans,
]);

//In the view 

@foreach($permintaans as $permintaan)
     <tr>{{$permintaan->tikpro->attribute}}</tr>
@endforeach
```

Another way like you've attempted is the join. In the select though I would leave it blank so you get all columns!

```
$permintaans = Permintaan::query()
->join('TIKPRO','TIKPRO.ID_TIKPRO','=','PERMINTAAN.TIKPRO_ID')
->get()
->all();
```

Comment: thanks for your answer :) But I prefer use the another one. Thankyou!